Navigation bar won't fit entirely on the screen
navigation bar problem
I'm having trouble regarding my navigation bar because it won't fit entirely on my screen when i'm decreasing the screen width when inspecting. What should I do?
I already tried some tricks like doing width: 100% but it just won't fix it.

Are you using a framework like bootstrap or something?
What are the width settings of the parent elements header,body and html?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
